# How should I fix this wiring?

Tags: electrical, heater

I’m replacing baseboard heaters in my house and the first one went in fine. The second however is causing a bit of an issue. When I took this heater out two sets of three wires were connected to this heater. Upon further investigation it looks like it controls the heater in the bathroom that are close by.

Is it safe to continue with this connection or should I put the bathroom on its own circuit? The bathroom heater is 240v 3.4amps and the heater going in the other room is 240v 6.3amps.

[image: wiring]

Comment: Welcome. Please revise to add more detail about the cables, wires and connections. Photos would be dandy. Also revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] for tips, and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. The two key limits are:

- No more than 80% of circuit capacity in continuous use. Heaters are assumed to be continuous use, but 3.4A + 6.3A = 9.7A and 80% of 15A is 12A, so you're fine. It may actually be a 20A circuit, which is also fine as long as all the wires are 12 AWG (can't tell from the picture if they are 14 AWG or 12 AWG).
- No receptacles if there >= 50% of circuit capacity used by hardwired equipment. This does apply here. However, since this is a 240V circuit and not a 240V/120V MWBC (clear because the cables are black/white and not black/red/white) and it is very rare to find 15A or 20A 240V circuits in the US except in workshops (for big tools) or in kitchens (for European appliances), it is very unlikely that you have any receptacles on the circuit.